Add substring to every non null cell through pandas
I have the following xlsx table as input, and i want to obtain the output with pandas.
Right now i am using openpyxl but the file is 8k rows and 200+ col, so the code i am using is not efficient and takes more than 20minutes to run.
The file as shown in the exampla has also NaN and empty cells, i want to modify only the cells that are not empty.
As shown in the code this block of code must work from column 2 and from row 5 to the end of the file.
# input
            Main_col        0    1    2
0  cas1 1_05.04.2024 16:40  A    B   
1  cas2 5_05.04.2024 16:41       C   
2  cas3 4_05.04.2024 17:30  D         E

# output
            Main_col                    0                          1                        2
0  cas1 1_05.04.2024 16:40  A_05.04.2024 16:40.cas1 1  B_05.04.2024 16:40.cas1 1                    
1  cas2 5_05.04.2024 16:41                             C_05.04.2024 16:41.cas2 5                    
2  cas3 4_05.04.2024 17:30  D_05.04.2024 17:30.cas3 4                            E_05.04.2024 17:30.cas3 4

the code i am using is the following.
for colonn in range(2,ws.max_column+1):
    #print("Elaboro colonna: " + str(colonn))
    for rig in range(5,ws.max_row+1):
        ValoreCell = str(ws.cell(rig,colonn).value)
        Valoreheader = str(ws.cell(rig,1).value)
        if ValoreCell != None and ValoreCell != " ":
            if "_" in ValoreCell:
                Valoreheader = Valoreheader.split("_")[0]
                #print("Valoreheader " + str(Valoreheader))
                Valor = ws.cell(rig,colonn).value
                ws.cell(rig,colonn).value = str(Valor) + "." + str(Valoreheader)

i am new in stackoverflow
a major improve in performance using pandas

Can you specify how long your loop approach takes?

40 minutes with openpyxl

@mozway 00:34:58 with the old method, 00:16:32 with your suggestions

You can build a mask, rework the Main_col string with str.replace and use boolean indexing with add to concatenate the strings:
# identify NaN/empty cells
mask = df.fillna('').ne('')
# exclude Main_col from mask
mask['Main_col'] = False

# reorder the "casX n_YYY" into "_YYY.casX n"
s = df['Main_col'].str.replace(r'([^ ]+) (\d)(_.*)', r'\3.\1 \2', regex=True)

# concatenate strings
df[mask] = df.astype(str).add(s, axis=0)

Output:
                  Main_col                          0                          1                          2
0  cas1 1_05.04.2024 16:40  A_05.04.2024 16:40.cas1 1  B_05.04.2024 16:40.cas1 1                           
1  cas2 5_05.04.2024 16:41                             C_05.04.2024 16:41.cas2 5                           
2  cas3 4_05.04.2024 17:30  D_05.04.2024 17:30.cas3 4                             E_05.04.2024 17:30.cas3 4

timing
on a 8k rows x 200 columns input:
374 ms ± 17.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

excluding the first N rows:
Just add one step to modify the mask
# exclude first N rows
N = 3
mask.iloc[:N] = False

Example output with N=3 and an input of 6 rows:
                  Main_col                          0                          1                          2
0  cas1 1_05.04.2024 16:40                          A                          B                           
1  cas2 5_05.04.2024 16:41                                                     C                           
2  cas3 4_05.04.2024 17:30                          D                                                     E
3  cas1 1_05.04.2024 16:40  A_05.04.2024 16:40.cas1 1  B_05.04.2024 16:40.cas1 1                           
4  cas2 5_05.04.2024 16:41                             C_05.04.2024 16:41.cas2 5                           
5  cas3 4_05.04.2024 17:30  D_05.04.2024 17:30.cas3 4                             E_05.04.2024 17:30.cas3 4


@jezrael yes, there is, also the other one was closed

I see, reopened.

how to exclude the first 6 rows of every column?

it is reopened because the old one has been closed without a valid solution. i tested it and it was not working but meanwhile the post was closed

@DavideC. you have to be careful how you design your questions, please read [ask]. You should make all details explicit directly in the question. One option, if I understand correctly, would be to use mask.iloc[:6] = False] to exclude the first 6 rows.

i think it was written in the last row of the post " As shown in the code this block of code must work from column 2 and from row 5 to the end of the file."

@DavideC. the approach I'm providing here is similar to the one in the other question. That said if you consider that the other question is not worth keeping, then you can delete it. The main issue in your previous question was the absence of a [mre] (which is better here).

is it possible to keep the posts alive until i try the solutions? there is some setting i have to do to my account to do so?

@DavideC. you can do as you want, but if you opened the second question because you were not happy with the answers of the first one this is not how it should have been done (question should have been edited and requested to reopen). Anyway, can you please test the above approach? This should work efficiently

i'll try asap, i see in the last result that is missing the casX Y in the values.

example: A1_05.04.2024 16:40 must be A1_05.04.2024 16:40.cas1 1

i tried the solution, this is what i got: A_05.04.2024 16:40cas1 1_05.04.2024 16:40 it should be: A_05.04.2024 16:40.cas1 1

@DavideC. this just needs a tiny modification of the regex, see update, but the logic is unchanged. Please try to understand how this is working, then you can tweak it easily to your needs. NB. comments are not good to paste large amounts of text.

unfortunately is still doing A_05.04.2024 16:40cas1 1_05.04.2024 16:40 rather than A_05.04.2024 16:40.cas1 1

@DavideC. please edit your question and provide a [mre] as code, for that export your DataFrame to dictionary with df.head(10).to_digt('tight') and add this to your question.

i found a problem in my code, the only thing missing is the point between A_05.04.2024 16:40 DOT cas1 1. like this A_05.04.2024 16:40.cas1 1 then the code works well

@DavideC. glad you could solve it. If you can indicate the timing of your original approach I'd be interested to compare it with this vectorial approach ;)

Is not solved, the only problem i see right now are that the order is different and is missing a .
Result:
Acas1 1_05.04.2024 16:40
expected:
A_05.04.2024 16:40.cas1 1
is missing a dot between A and cas1 1 and the order of the elements is not as the expected one.

@mozway i added the "DOT" but don't understand how to swap date and value

@DavideC.sorry but I cannot understand your issue, my code seems to give the exact expected output.

You may use the where method. Assuming your dataframe is named df and all the columns are of string type:
for col in df.columns.difference(["Main_col"]):
    df[col] = df[col].where(df[col].isna(), other=df[col] + df["Main_col"].str[1:] + " " + df["Main_col"].str[0]


This solution only uses pandas and is much faster since it uses only one loop and a vectorized method.
Another option is to use numpy.where, which I prefer since it has a much clearer syntax:
import numpy as np

for col in df.columns.difference(["Main_col"]):
    df[col] = np.where(df[col].notna(), df[col] + df["Main_col"].str[1:] + " " + df["Main_col"].str[0], df[col])


Documentation:

pandas where
numpy.where


It actually uses more than one loop, .str[1:] is a wrapper around a loop ;) Also, as shown in my answer, you can directly "vectorize" the operation at the DataFrame level (although with strings this is never a true vectorization).
